# Json request retrieving results but only displaying the first result

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview which is getting data from an api request, from that request its only displaying the first result.

```
//MARK:-- Computed vars
var listOfLodges = [LodgeDetail](){
    didSet{
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.navigationItem.title = "\(self.listOfLodges.count) lodges found"
            print("\(self.listOfLodges.count) lodges found") // returns 11 lodges
            print(" ")
        }
    }
}
```

this displays 11 returned results, all the data is different.

```
//MARK: -- ViewDidLoad
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            loadData()
        }

//MARK:-- Setting up Table view
    @objc func setDelegate(){
        let landing = LandingViewController()
        landing.delegate = self
    }
 
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return listOfLodges.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
```

this is probably where my errors are, I am unsure of what could be going wrong?

```
// possible errors here
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for:indexPath)
        let lodge = listOfLodges[indexPath.row]
        let rating: String = String(lodge.rating!)//careful force unwrapping 

        print(rating) // prints the same 4.2
        print(lodge.name) //prints the same name
       
        return cell
    }
}
//MARK:-- Functions called on did load
extension ListViewController{
    func loadData(){
        let lodgeRequest = LodgeRequest(lat:passedLat, long:passedLong)
        lodgeRequest.getLodges{[weak self] result in
                    switch result{
                    case.failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    case.success(let lodges):
                        self?.listOfLodges = lodges
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
let lodge = listOfLodges[indexPath.row]
```

to

```
let lodge = listOfLodges[indexPath.section]
```

As you only have one row per section then `indexPath.row` is always `0` so first item is displayed for all sections